# Зачем нужны препроцессоры?

Tags: css, layout

Скажите, в каких ситуациях используют к примеру less если есть postcss с кучей полезных плагинов?
например nextCss

Comment: Когда появился less, никакого postcss ещё не существовало. Никто не заставляет вас использовать less в 2019 году

Comment: https://xakep.ru/2014/05/18/razbiraemsya-v-otlichiyah-preprotsessorov-css/

Comment: Я имею ввиду ситуацию в которой использовали бы и то и другое

Comment: Спрашивайте тех, кто использует

Comment: Я взял это с требований на вакансиях) что вы мне щас скажете? что бы я работодателя спрашивал об этом?